# Substituting "+-" with a "-" in a string in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a string :

```
s="a+3*b+4*c+-5*d+-6*e"
```

I want to convert this to:

```
s_want="a+3*b+4*c-5*d-6*e"
```

here "+-" is being replaced by "-". I tried following

```
> gsub("+-","-",s)
[1] "a+3*b+4*c+-5*d+-6*e"
```

as you can see this just doesn't work. In fact i tried the same with some other replacement as well.

```
> gsub("+-","XX",s)
[1] "a+3*b+4*c+XX5*d+XX6*e"
```

It seems "+" sign is invisible to R. I suspect it has something to do with regex. let me search and will post updates if i find something. Thanks.
Update:
After a little search i found "fixed=T" is the solution that i was looking for.

```
> gsub("+-","-",s,fixed=T)
[1] "a+3*b+4*c-5*d-6*e"
```

Thanks everyone who bothered to search for solution anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `+` is a special meta character in regex (*which repeats the previous token one or more times*), you need to escape it or put the `+` inside a character class (*`[+]`*), in-order to match a literal `+` symbol.

```
gsub("\\+-","-",s)
```

OR

```
gsub("[+]-","-",s)
```

Comment: If you consider posting the same solution is okay, then I will delete mine even though I posted it first

Comment: @akrun yep, i agree you the one posted first but i see a lookahead based regex at very first. Later you edited the answer and added the second one.

Comment: I posted that first followed the new one but when I updated there was no other solution here (I guess I am right).  Anyway, no problem.

Comment: @akrun you should not have deleted you answer if you had posted first :)

Comment: Thanks. I have added an alternate solution as well as update to my query.